# Link on image shows border around the image in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a problem with links on images in Internet Explorer.
I used the following code:
`<a href="link.html"><img src="image.jpg"></a>`
Now there is a strange border around the image. I tried `a { text-decoration: none; }` but it does not change anything. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put this in css

```
a img{border:none;}
```

Comment: +1. This basic property can be found in the majority of reset css files, normalize.css and HTML5 boilerplate.

Answer (score 2):

When ever I get that problem I use `outline : none`
See if that works for you.

Or

```
area {
    outline : none;
}
```

If you want to cover more than one element